# How to understand this field redefinition example from path integral formalism?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, path-integral, dimensional-regularization, functional-determinants

I'm studying the Lagrangian
$$
\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2}\partial_\mu\phi \partial^\mu\phi+\lambda\phi\partial_\mu\phi\partial^\mu\phi~=~\frac{1}{2}(1+2\lambda \phi)\partial_\mu\phi \partial^\mu\phi.\tag{1}
$$
We can take the field redefinition to make it looks like free field theory:
$$
\frac{1}{2}(\partial\phi')^2 = \frac{1}{2}(\partial\phi)^2+\lambda\phi(\partial\phi)^2\tag{2}
$$
and we can solve and obtain that
$$
\phi' = \frac{1}{3\lambda}(1+2\lambda\phi)^{3/2}.\tag{3}
$$
My question is since this redefinition is non-linear, how can we see
$$
\int\mathcal{D}\phi\rightarrow\int\mathcal{D}\phi'\tag{4}
$$
produce the same theory? I heard about this would give an additional Jacobi factor, which
vanishes in dimensional regularization because it’s scaleless, but I don't know how to make sense of this. Also, how can we tell if a field could be redefined?

Comment: Page 11 of these notes https://courses.edx.org/c4x/MITx/8.EFTx/asset/notes_EFT.pdf discusses the "Representation Independence Theorem" that is probably what you are looking for, with some details. I don't understand it well enough to write more, I'll try to think about it though

Comment: How did you manage to solve that equation? In any case, the allowed field redefinitions (i.e. those for which the physics remains unchanged) are of the form $\phi \to f(\phi)$ where $f(\phi) = \phi + {\cal O}(\phi^2)$ near $\phi = 0$. Your field redefinition does not satisfy this.

Comment: @Prahar Thanks for the comment! I got $\partial_\mu\phi'=\partial_\mu\phi\sqrt{1+2\lambda\phi}$, this could be obtained by adding $\partial_\mu$ on both sides of that redefinition.

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes, OP's field redefinition (3) can be made perturbative by a simple shift:
   $$ \phi^{\prime}~=~\frac{1}{3\lambda}(1+2\lambda\phi)^{3/2}-\frac{1}{3\lambda}~=~\phi+{\cal O}(\phi^2).\tag{3'}$$
2. Moreover, in dimensional regularization the Jacobian is 1 due to the presence of $\delta^d(0)$, cf. e.g. my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/455839/2451).

Comment: Thanks so much!!