# Hamilton's equation for generating functional

Tags: gauge-theory, hamiltonian-formalism, path-integral, constrained-dynamics, quantization

I've been reading E. S. Fradkin and G. A. Vilkovisky, “Quantization of Relativistic Systems with Constraints: Equivalence of Canonical and Covariant Formalisms in Quantum Theory of Gravitational Field.” 1977. [Online]. Available: https://inspirehep.net/literature/120057
, and I am having some trouble understanding the way he solves the equations of motion for the generating functional. The paper does point to references that apparently explain this better but I haven't been able to find online versions of them and due to the pandemic I do not have access to my institutions library.

Let $\eta^A=(q^i,p_i)$ be the canonical variables of some system with Hamiltonian $H$ and subject to only second-class constraints $\Psi^a$. Let $J_A$ be external sources and define the interaction Hamiltonian $H_\text{int}=\eta^AJ_A$. Let $Z[J]$ be the generating functional for Green's functions
$$\langle 0|T(\eta^{A_1}(t_1)\cdots\eta^{A_n}(t_n))|0\rangle=\frac{\delta Z[J]}{\delta iJ_{A_1}(t_1)\cdots\delta iJ_{A_n}(t_n)}|_{J=0}.$$
In other words, for every polynomial $F[\eta]$ we have
$$\langle 0|TF[\eta]|0\rangle=F[\eta]|_{\eta=\frac{\delta}{\delta iJ}}Z[J]|_{J=0}.$$

Now, the first thing is that if we want an operator equation $F[\eta]=0$ to be satisfied by our theory, we want that all matrix elements of this form vanish
$$0=\langle 0|T(F[\eta]\eta^{A_1}(t_1)\cdots\eta^{A_n}(t_n))|0\rangle=\frac{\delta }{\delta iJ_{A_1}(t_1)\cdots\delta iJ_{A_n}(t_n)}F[\eta]|_{\eta=\frac{\delta}{\delta iJ}}Z[J]|_{J=0}.$$
This determines the Taylor coefficients forming the equation of motion for the generating functional
$$0=F[\eta]|_{\eta=\frac{\delta}{\delta iJ}}Z[J].$$
My first question is whether this logic is indeed correct or if I am missing some subtlety here.

Now, in our particular case the equations of motion are
$$\left(\dot{\eta}-\{\eta,H+H_\text{int}\}_D\right)|_{\eta=\frac{\delta}{\delta iJ}}Z[J]=0,$$
$$\Psi^a|_{\eta=\frac{\delta}{\delta iJ}}Z[J]=0,$$
where
$$\{A,B\}_D=\{A,B\}-\{A,\Psi^a\}Q_{ab}\{\Psi^b,B\},$$
is the Dirac bracket. In here $Q_{ab}$ is the inverse matrix to $\{\Psi^a,\Psi^b\}$. With our logic above, it is clear that the $J$'s appearing in the bracket are on the left of the $\delta/\delta iJ$.The paper proceeds to say that these equations can be equivalently written as
$$\left(\dot{\eta}-\left\{\eta,H+H_\text{int}+\Psi^a\xi_a-\frac{1}{2i}\delta^{(1)}(0)\log\det\{\Psi^a,\Psi^b\}\right\}\right)|_{\eta=\frac{\delta}{\delta iJ}}Z[J]=0,$$
$$\Psi^a|_{\eta=\frac{\delta}{\delta iJ}}Z[J]=0.$$
I don't understand how this comes about. He mentions that the $\xi_a$ are determined by the consistency conditions. I imagine this means that (as in the classical case) they are given by demanding that the constraints are constant
$$\xi_a=-Q_{ab}\{\Psi^b,H\}.$$
Is this correct? In that case however, I would obtain the equation above by expanding the Dirac bracket except for the $\det\{\Psi^a,\Psi^b\}$ part. Where does this come from?

Finally, my last question is how does one integrate this equation. The paper states the solution is
$$Z[J]=\int\mathcal{D}q\mathcal{D}p\mathcal{D}\xi\prod_{t}\sqrt{\det\{\Psi^\bullet,\Psi^\bullet\}}\exp\left(i\int dt\,(p\dot{q}-H-H_\text{int}-\Psi\xi)\right).$$

Answer (score 1):

1. We start from the Hamiltonian action
   $$ S ~=~\int \! dt~ L, \tag{1.15a}$$
   with Hamiltonian Lagrangian
   $$\begin{align}  L~=~&\vartheta_I(z) \dot{z}^{I} - H - \Psi^a\xi_a\cr
   &- i\hbar \delta(0) \ln {\rm Pf}(Q^{\cdot\cdot})
   - i\hbar \delta(0) \ln {\rm Pf}(\omega_{\cdot\cdot}) , \end{align} \tag{1.15b}$$
   and with Hamiltonian
   $$ H~=~H_0 + H_{\rm int}, \tag{2.5a}$$
   $$z^I~=~(q^i,p_i), \qquad  H_{\rm int} ~=~-J_I z^I-j^a\xi_a,\tag{2.5b}$$
   Here $\Psi^a$ are $2m$ [second-class constraints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_class_constraint),
   $$ Q^{ab}~=~\{\Psi^a,\Psi^b\} \quad \text{invertible},\tag{1.17}$$
   $\xi_a$ are Lagrange multipliers,
   and $$\vartheta~=~\vartheta_I\mathrm{d}z^I\tag{A}$$ is a symplectic 1-form potential, where
   $$ \omega_{IJ}~=~\partial_I\vartheta_J - \partial_J\vartheta_I\tag{B}$$
   is the components of a [symplectic 2-form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_manifold)
   $$\omega~=~\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{d}z^I \omega_{IJ} \wedge \mathrm{d}z^J~=~\mathrm{d}\vartheta. \tag{C}$$
   The appearance of $\delta(0)$ is e.g. explained in [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/127705/2451) Phys.SE post.
2. The classical EOMs are
   $$ \Psi^a~\approx~0, \tag{1.19}$$
   $$ \dot{z}^I~\approx~\{z^I,H\}_D
   ~\approx~ \{z^I,H\}+\{z^I,\Psi^a\}\xi_a, \tag{1.18}$$
   $$\xi_a~\approx~ -Q^{-1}_{ab}\{\Psi^b,H\}. \tag{1.20}$$
3. The solution to the corresponding path integral
   $$\begin{align} Z[J,j] ~=~&\int\! {\cal D}\frac{z}{\sqrt{\hbar}}~{\cal D}\xi~  \exp\left(\frac{i}{\hbar}S\right)\cr
   ~=~&\int\! {\cal D}\frac{z}{\sqrt{\hbar}}~
   \exp\left(\frac{i}{\hbar}\int\!dt \left(\vartheta_I(z) \dot{z}^{I} - H \right)\right)\cr
   &\times \delta(\Psi^{\cdot}){\rm Pf}(Q^{\cdot\cdot}) {\rm Pf}(\omega_{\cdot\cdot})
   \end{align}\tag{2.8}$$
   was first written down in Ref. 2. The [Pfaffians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pfaffian) are needed to ensure that the path integral (2.8) is invariant under reparametrizations of the $z^I$-coordinates and the second-class constraints $\Psi^a$.
4. Ignoring boundary terms, we immediately derive that the solution (2.8) satisfies
   $$\begin{align} 0~=~&\frac{\hbar}{i} \int\! {\cal D}\frac{z}{\sqrt{\hbar}}~{\cal D}\xi~ \frac{\delta e^{iS/\hbar} }{\delta z^I(t)}  \cr
   ~=~&\int\! {\cal D}\frac{z}{\sqrt{\hbar}}~{\cal D}\xi~ \frac{\delta S}{\delta z^I(t)} \exp\left(\frac{i}{\hbar}S\right) \cr
   ~=~&\left. \frac{\delta S}{\delta z^I(t)} \right|_{z=\frac{\hbar}{i}\frac{\delta}{\delta J},\xi=\frac{\hbar}{i}\frac{\delta}{\delta j}}Z[J,j],
   \end{align} \tag{2.7a}$$
   and
   $$\begin{align} 0~=~&\frac{\hbar}{i} \int\! {\cal D}\frac{z}{\sqrt{\hbar}}~{\cal D}\xi~ \frac{\delta e^{iS/\hbar} }{\delta \xi_a(t)}  \cr
   ~=~&\int\! {\cal D}\frac{z}{\sqrt{\hbar}}~{\cal D}\xi~ \frac{\delta S}{\delta  \xi_a(t)} \exp\left(\frac{i}{\hbar}S\right) \cr
   ~=~&\left. \Psi^a(t) \right|_{z=\frac{\hbar}{i}\frac{\delta}{\delta J},\xi=\frac{\hbar}{i}\frac{\delta}{\delta j}}Z[J,j].
   \end{align}\tag{2.7b} $$
   In practice it is a bit more challenging to derive the solution (2.8) from the consistency conditions (2.7), cf. OP's question.

References:

1. E.S. Fradkin & G.A. Vilkovisky, [*Quantization of Relativistic Systems with Constraints: Equivalence of Canonical and Covariant Formalisms in Quantum Theory of Gravitational Field*](https://inspirehep.net/literature/120057), 1977.
2. P. Senjanovic, *Path Integral Quantization of Field Theories with Second Class Constraints,* [Annals Phys. 100 (1976) 227](https://doi.org/10.1016/0003-4916(76)90062-2).