# Delta function squared in Weigand's QFT notes

Tags: quantum-field-theory, dirac-delta-distributions, regularization

On page 74 of [Timo Weigand's QFT notes](https://www.physics.umd.edu/grt/taj/624b/WeigandQFT.pdf), right at the top, the following equality is used:

$$\left[(2\pi)^4\delta^{(4)}(p_f-p_i)\right]^2=(2\pi)^4\delta^{(4)}(p_f-p_i)(2\pi)^4\delta^{(4)}(0) \tag{2.167},$$

however I cannot figure out why this should be the case. I can't even see where to begin, could someone more enlightened please explain this step?

Comment: $\delta\left(0\right)$ is not defined normally. You would need non-standard analysis to square a delta. Or it is a sloppy notation for a limit of test functions that is later repaired by "dividing by $\delta\left(0\right)$". See, for example, (2.149), looking equally dodgy to me without further context - which I'm sure there must be. And there is: See e.g. chapter 1.8.

Comment: For regular functions $f$ there is the rule $\delta\left(x\right) f\left(x\right) = \delta\left(x\right) f\left(0\right)$, which is easily proven by applying this distribution to a test function and seeing that the delta fixes the argument of $f$ to zero. This makes the formula at least seem plausible in analogy, but again: it looks dodgy.

Comment: These are all idealized limits. You may regularize everything by suitable spacetime volume normalizations.  This is what the explanatory Volume pointer in the complete formula *means*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The square of the [Dirac delta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) does not make mathematical sense, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/47934/2451) Phys.SE post.
2. However, physicists often implicitly imply that the spacetime is a finite (large) box. Then momentum eigenvalues become discrete, integrals are replaced by sums, Dirac delta distributions are replaced by [Kronecker delta functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta), etc., cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/127705/2451) Phys.SE post. In this regularization, one can make sense of $\delta(0)$ and eq. (2.167).