# How to understand this Dirac delta function?

Tags: fourier-transform, dirac-delta-distributions, discrete, volume, lattice-model

I am reading [this](https://www.phys.ksu.edu/personal/wysin/notes/quantumEM.pdf) paper about quantization of the electromagnetic field, and there is a point where the author imposes the fundamental commutation relation between the vector potential and its canonical momentum:
$$[A_i(\mathbf r,t), p_i(\mathbf r',t)] = \frac{i\hbar}{4V}\sum_{\mathbf k}{(2e^{i\mathbf k\cdot(\mathbf r-\mathbf r')} + 2e^{-i\mathbf k\cdot(\mathbf r-\mathbf r')})} = i\hbar \delta(\mathbf r-\mathbf r')$$
I could follow how the sum is derived. But not why this is a delta function.

The author makes a remark that this is a finite volume. I suppose that this delta function is then defined so that: $$\int_V\delta(\mathbf r-\mathbf r')d^3r' = 1.$$

Considering that this volume is a period, the meaning would be: $\int_V e^{i\mathbf k\cdot(\mathbf r-\mathbf r')} = 0$ for $\mathbf r\neq\mathbf r'$ for all $k$'s. But the problem is that for $\mathbf r = \mathbf r'$, $$\frac{i\hbar}{4V}\sum_{\mathbf k}{(2e^{i\mathbf k\cdot(\mathbf r-\mathbf r')} + 2e^{-i\mathbf k\cdot(\mathbf r-\mathbf r')})} = \frac{i\hbar}{V}\sum_{\mathbf k}cos(\mathbf k\cdot \mathbf 0)\implies $$

$$\int_V\sum_{\mathbf k}cos(\mathbf k\cdot \mathbf 0)d^3r' = V(1 + 1 + 1 +...) = \infty$$ instead of $V$ as required.

Comment: For $\mathbf{r} = \mathbf{r}'$, the right-hand side should be $i \hbar \delta(0)$, which is indeed supposed to be infinite, not just $V$. If you want a finite result, you have to integrate both sides of the equation against some $f(\mathbf{r})$.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/127705/2451

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider Fourier series expansion of the periodic function
$$\sum_{\ell,m,n}\delta(x-\ell L)\delta(y-m M)\delta(z-nN)=\sum_{\ell,m,n}c_{\ell mn}e^{i2\pi\ell x/L}e^{i2\pi m y/M}e^{i2\pi n z/N}$$
Multiply both sides by $e^{-i2\pi\ell' x/L}e^{-i2\pi m' y/M}e^{-i2\pi n' z/N}$, integrate within a single "unit cell" of volume $LMN$, and use the orthogonality of these functions to conclude
$$c_{\ell'm'n'}=\frac{1}{LMN}$$
and thus
$$\sum_{\ell,m,n}\delta(x-\ell L)\delta(y-m M)\delta(z-nN)=\frac{1}{LMN}\sum_{\ell,m,n}e^{i2\pi\ell x/L}e^{i2\pi m y/M}e^{i2\pi n z/N}$$
or in your language
$$\sum_{\mathbf R}\delta(\mathbf r - \mathbf R) = \frac 1 V \sum_{\mathbf k}e^{i\mathbf k \cdot \mathbf r}$$
If we are only evaluating this function within a single "unit cell", e.g. the one containing $\mathbf r = 0$, then only one term of the sum on the left-hand side is non-zero and we are left with
$$\delta(\mathbf r) = \frac 1 V \sum_{\mathbf k}e^{i\mathbf k \cdot \mathbf r}.$$

I've skipped some steps, and you can ask reasonable questions like "does a periodic impulse train even have a Fourier series", but this is one way to obtain this relation. Also see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Fourier_kernels).

---

A more direct approach is to note that
$$\sum_{\ell = -{\ell_0}}^{\ell_0} e^{i2\pi\ell x/L}=\frac{\sin[(l_0 + \frac 1 2)2\pi x/L]}{\sin(\pi x/L)}.$$
This follows from the [partial sum of the geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Sum) and the fact that $\sin z = (e^{iz}-e^{-iz})/(2i)$. Lor large $\ell_0$, this is an oscillatory function bounded by the envelope provided by the denominator, with a very sharp peak at $x = 0$. It can be shown that its integral on any interval containing $x = 0$ converges to $1/L$ as $\ell_0\to\infty$, consistent with $\delta(x)/L$.

While the value of the sum does not strictly converge at $x\ne 0$, the sum gets increasingly oscillatory for large $\ell_0$ such that its integral on any interval not containing $x = 0$ converges to zero. As such, in a distribution sense we are justified in writing
$$\frac 1 L\sum_{\ell = -\infty}^{\infty} e^{i2\pi\ell x/L}=\delta(x).$$

This can be extended in the straightforward way to 3D to arrive at the result obtained by the Fourier series approach.

---

In your last line of equations, you are evaluating $\int_V \delta(0) d^3\mathbf r'$, so it is no surprise you get an infinity.

Comment: One difficulty I have with your last expression (which is in the article) is: $\delta(0) = \infty$ as a good delta function. But $\delta(x)$ for $x\neq 0$ is a sum of trigonometric functions. And it is not zero, as expected for a delta function.

Comment: @ClaudioSaspinski Why do you assume it is not zero?

Comment: Well, unless it is a sum of trigonometric functions with equal steps along the period. In this case yes, it is zero.

Comment: @ClaudioSaspinski See my addition. The intuitive way to think about it is that the sinusoidal functions are all in phase and add "constructively" at $x = 0$, whereas for $x\ne 0$ you have lots of components with essentially random phase adding in no preferential way so that the sum is *essentially* converges to zero. [This phenomenon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_phase_approximation) pops up often in physics, e.g. in analyzing the interference pattern of many slits or in the classical limit of the Feynman path integral formulation.

Comment: It is then not a conventional Dirac delta function with infinity at zero and sharp decrease to zero nearby. There is a sharp peak going to infinity at zero, and a noise that is much lower but not zero.

Comment: @ClaudioSaspinski It is a valid representation of the $\delta$ [distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)) because it satisfies the property that $\int f(x)\delta(x)~dx$ is $f(0)$ for any interval that contains $x = 0$ and zero for any interval that doesn't, for a smooth function $f$. If it behaves like a delta "function" under an integral, it is a delta "function".